# Kernighan and Ritchie Exercise 5-11 is unclear

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Here's Exercise 5-11:
Modify the program entab and detab (written as exercises in Chapter 1) to
accept a list of tab stops as arguments. Use the default tab settings if there are no arguments.

entab is described as

Replace strings of blanks by minimum # of tabs/blanks to achieve same spacing.
A tab should be given preference to let the array of chars store the "tab" as one index
rather than multiple spaces.

What is a "tab stop" exactly and how can we accept a list of whatever the tab stops are? I'm confused.

Comment: Tab stops are "the next place where the cursor stops" when you hit tab (or print \t). It allows you to align text in columns - instead of counting characters and spaces. This is even more important with proportional fonts but this exercise is for mono space fonts, I believe.

Comment: To get help "accepting a list of stops" you need to show your code. Most likely you will pass an `int[]` array and the number of stops as another `int`

Comment: I was having problems understanding the question so no code was written yet. Right now I believe the program wants the user to enter stops in the form of an int[] array. Thank you @Floris!

Comment: In the olden days, when K&R was written, typewriters had `tab stops` which configured how far the paper would move left each time that the `TAB` key was pressed. So a list of `tab stops` is a list of monotonically increasing column numbers, such as `6,16,32,40,72,80`.

Comment: Thanks, @markgz. There's just some things young timers like myself won't get from books.

Comment: Tab stops exactly like those of typewriters still exist in virtually every word processing program, and many text editors. "young timers like myself won't get from books" -- Gee, and here I thought young timers are familiar with all the new fangled technology like *google* and *Wikipedia* : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop

Comment: @JimBalter Thank you. I did look up tab stops but I wasn't keen on how it was relevant because the Wikipedia article is about typewriters and left-right-and-center types which isn't what this question is talking about. As for Google and Wikipedia, thanks for pointing out these websites. The main reason for my confusion was how replacing a number of spaces with a tab is related to accepting custom tab stops as numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you hit `tab`, you travel to the next tab stop.  For example, many text editors have the tab stops at all multiples of 8 (8, 16, 24, 32, 40, etc) so if you are in column (say) 11 and hit tab you go to column 16.  If you're in column 14 and hit tab you also go to column 16.  So a tab is not always worth a fixed amount of spaces, but however many are needed to go to the next tab stop.

Comment: Thank you. The book never goes over tab stops. And your username fits :P

Comment: @JimBalter Again, I almost forgot you mentioning google 3 inches above this comment on this page so thank you for mentioning that again. The linux page helped but I thought I could get a clearer, more colloquial, what-was-relevant answer here by more seasoned readers.